# Modifying JS to stop animation - HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```js
(function() {

  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
  }

  showNextQuote();

})();
```

```css
.quotes {
  display : none;
  margin  : 0;
  padding : 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1> Hello </h1>
<div class="quotes">
  <h1> There </h1>
</div>
<div class="quotes">
  <h1> World </h1>
</div>
```

How can I modify the JS so that once the text alternates **once**, it stops. I basically want to stop it from continuously alternating and want it to stop when the text basically reaches `World` since the first cycle of alternating text will be completed. How can I modify the JS for this?

Comment: why not doing it in CSS?  it would be more simple !

Comment: I would go for css solution, however, I already have it setup fine in my website and its working as desired since I had to make a couple of changes to other css. Can you suggest a way for this? @MisterJojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a limit condition to go to the next iteration. In this case, is not a loop, so `quoteIndex % quotes.length` is not needed.

```js
(function() {

  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    var q=quotes.eq(quoteIndex)
      .fadeIn(2000)
    if (quoteIndex < quotes.length-1)
      q.delay(2000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
  }

  showNextQuote();

})();
```

```css
.quotes {
  display : none;
  margin  : 0;
  padding : 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1> Hello </h1>
<div class="quotes">
  <h1> There </h1>
</div>
<div class="quotes">
  <h1> World </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS only :

```css
#quotes > h1:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity   : 0;
  animation-delay     : .5s;
  animation-duration  : 4s;
  animation-fill-mode : forwards;
  animation-name      : show2Hide2;
  }
#quotes > h1:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity   : 0;
  height    : 0;
  margin    : 0;
  animation-delay     : 4.5s;
  animation-duration  : 2s;
  animation-fill-mode : forwards;
  animation-name      : wait4show2;
  }
@keyframes show2Hide2 {
  0%   { opacity : 0; }
  50%  { opacity : 1; }
  99%  { opacity : 0; }
  100% { height  : 0; margin: 0; }
  }
@keyframes wait4show2 {
  0%   { height  : auto; margin: auto; opacity : 0; }
  100% { opacity : 1; }
  }
```

```html
<h1> Hello </h1>
<div id="quotes">
  <h1> There </h1>
  <h1> World </h1>
</div>
```